# How to fit data using integral

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a set of real data points $v_1\dots v_n \in R^1$. I would like to find two parameters $s$ and $m$ such that the following holds
$$
\left|\int_a^{b}f_n(x)P(x,s,m)dx - v_n \right| < \delta.
$$

That is, I have to find the proper values of two parameters, so that I fit a set of predefined data values. The functions $f_n(x)$, as well as the integral bounds are always $>0$. More precisely $f_n(x)$ are interaction probabilities from particle physics. The role of the weighting function is to adjust the integrand, so that my target value is found. I tried weighting function $P(x,s,m)$ of the form

$$
P(x,s,m)=1-\left(\frac{s}{x}\right)^m  \text{  for   } x>s \text{ and zero otherwise}
$$

Note, that this would reduce the value of the integral in the limit $s\to b$ and $s\to0$. Basically setting the parameter $s$ mimics increasing the lower bound of the integral. I tried to optimize this using the standard package lmfit from Python, but somehow didn't get very satisfactory results. Since I am new to optimization problems I would appreciate your help and ideas. For instance, one possibility might be to use a better choice of the weighting function. 
Thank you in advance

Edit

Simple python example using lmfit. In this case only direct usage of quad from scypy with unknown parameters slope and lower bound can be used to optimize. Somehow fit_int fails

```
import lmfit 
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import random


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
NDATA=111

x=np.linspace(0,1,1000)
datax=np.linspace(0,10,NDATA)
data=np.zeros(NDATA)

def cut_func(x,xm,a):
    x[x==0.] = 1e-30
    v = (1.-(xm/x)**a) * (x > xm)
    v[np.isnan(v)] = 0.
    return v



def model(x,s=2.1):
        return np.exp(x*s)+x*s

def step(x,u):
    return 1 * (x > u)    

def fit_intg(c,s):
# use either step or cut_func
# cut func approaches step for large slopes    
#    f=step(x,c)
    f=cut_func(x,c,0)    
    f1=model(x,s)
    v=np.trapz(f*f1,x)
    return v

for i in range(NDATA):

    v=quad(model,0,0.712)    
    data[i]=v[0]*(1.+0*random.uniform(-0.01,0.01))

print('Exact', quad(model,0,0.712)[0])
print('Quad intagral', 1./2.1*(np.exp(2.1*0.712)-1.)+2.1*(0.712**2)/2.)
plt.scatter(datax,data)
print('Integral using the fit function, not that precise',fit_intg(0.712,2.1))


params = lmfit.Parameters()
params.add('slope', value=2.1, min=0.1, max=3)
params.add('cut', value= 0.1, min=0.0, max=3)



def residual(params):
    v=np.zeros(NDATA)   
    for i in range(NDATA):
# two options to do the fit
# direct via the model or with integral
# works fine        
    #  val= quad(model,0,params['cut'].value,args=(params['slope'].value,))[0]
# does not work
      val=fit_intg(params['cut'].value,params['slope'].value)
      v[i]= val
    return v - data 


print("#"*80)

out1 = lmfit.minimize(residual,params,method='nelder')
out = lmfit.minimize(residual,out1.params,method='nelder')
print(lmfit.report_fit(out))


v=quad(model,0,out.params['cut'].value,args=(out.params['slope'].value,))

plt.axhline(v[0])


plt.xlabel('slope')
plt.ylabel('cut')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add and example of the function $f_n(x)$ and a few (mock) values for $v_n$?

Comment: Thank You for your reply. The functions are measured distributions. Unfortunately I can't express them in closed form. I am not Sure how go put links here. But You could get an idea by looking at a picture of NaI spectrum. I can also provide a script where i try ti apply This trick to $e^{ax}$. I first generate some integrals plus minus random fluctuation ans try ti fit.

Comment: I see ... still believe that if you could post a little example you may get a useful answer to your question

Comment: Hi I included a sample code that illustrates my problem. By uncommenting one of the two options in Te residual function one can try to optimize a set of pre-calculated values.Hope this will make my question more precise. Thank you for the help

Comment: Maybe I'm getting this wrong, but the result of the function of the function ``fit_intg`` is always zero, since it is the result of multiplying something by the the output of ``cut_func(x, c, 0)`` which is always zero

Comment: Hello ans thank You again for your comment. Actually, cut_gunc doesn't  always return zero . Only nan are set to zero via v[np.isnan(v)] = 0. This unfolds to in pseudocode  for all v== nan set v=0.